# What does 10-digit output of QImage::pixel function specifically mean?

Tags: c++, image, colors, qt5, pixel

I'm currently using Qt 5.12.3 and having problems with understanding the 10-digit output of QImage::pixel function. For this code:

```
QImage image;
image.load("D:/qtProjects/../image.png", "PNG");

for(int i = 0 ; i < 1920; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < 1080; j++)
            std:: cout << image.pixel(i, j) << "\n";
```

in a part of the console output I'm receiving:

4278190080
4278651664
4278585871
4278651664

The problem is that I cannot understand how to use those 10-digit numbers in online calculators to see the actual pixel color. All I know is that it somehow interprets colors in ARGB or RGBA formats.
Thanks for attention!

Comment: Convert the numbers to hexadecimal. All will be revealed! OK, something will be revealed. Clue: FF is probably "opaque"

Comment: It's RGBA represented as a 32-bit unsigned integer. Print it in hexadecimal: write `cout << hex;` once before your loops, and the number will be AARRGGBB (i may not remember the order of color channels correctly!), when A is alpha, R is red etc.

Comment: Decimal is a really shitty base to print RGBA values in.

Comment: Thanks it all helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make image manipulation easier you can use the class `QColor`. As many other Qt classes you can output it to the console with `qDebug()`. You need to include `<QDebug>` to have it available. Here an example how to use `QColor` with `QImage`:

```
QImage image;
image.load("D:/qtProjects/../image.png", "PNG");

QColor colorRead(image.pixel(0, 0));    // get color of pixel 0,0
qDebug() << colorRead;                  // output color with float values 0 - 1
qDebug() << "R: " << colorRead.red();   // output components of color as int 0 - 255
qDebug() << "G: " << colorRead.green();
qDebug() << "B: " << colorRead.blue();
qDebug() << "A: " << colorRead.alpha();

QColor colorWrite(0, 0, 255);           // instantiate other color
image.setPixelColor(0, 0, colorWrite);  // set pixel 0,0 to the color
```

Possible Output:

```
QColor(ARGB 1, 0.305882, 0.305882, 0.211765)
R:  78
G:  78
B:  54
A:  255
```

Comment: Thanks for a very specific answer, perfect for me to use.

Answer (score 1):

These numbers are the 4 color components (red, green, blue, and alpha, 8 bits each, and not necessarily in that order,) packed into a 32-bit unsigned integer.

To extract these components, in essence you need to extract the value of all the bytes that comprise a 4-byte integer. To do that, you have several ways but the easiest one to understand is probably this: successive division by 256.

Since each byte's value is in the range [0..255], you will extract 1 byte's worth of information each time you calculate the remainder of the division of that big number by 256 (think of a byte as a base-256 digit.)

So, here's the code:

```
unsigned char b0 = x % 256;
x = x / 256;
unsigned char b1 = x % 256;
x = x / 256;
unsigned char b2 = x % 256;
x = x / 256;
unsigned char b3 = x % 256;
```

In the above code, `b0` will receive the value of the least significant byte in `x`, and `b3` will have the most significant one. Which of them will be which component will be dependent on the order of the color components (whether it's RGBA or BGRA or ARGB or ABGR,) and most probably also on the endianness of your machine. But I think it will be easy to figure it out.

Given the look of the sample numbers you've posted, I think the most significant byte of the number is the alpha channel (i.e. `b3` in my code gives you the alpha value,) and that probably makes `b0` to be red, `b1` to be green, and `b2` to be blue. Probably.

Comment: Thanks for help! Found out that QImage::pixel returns pixel stats in AARRGGBB format. After seeing both number formats it is clear for me that 2^32 -1 is a 10-digit decimal number and 8-digit hexadecimal number (FFFFFFFF) -> 32 bits are required to correctly represent any ARGB stats, just as you said.